# Angular: ngModel não está sendo reconhecido

Tags: javascript, html, angular, front-end, binding

Estou usando ngModel para inserir valor na variável através do input, mas o mesmo não está sendo reconhecido, se eu faço com valores isolados ele não retorna nada, se eu tento com objeto ele retorna *undefined*

**Template html:**

```
<form class="form-signin">    
   <div class="form-label-group"> 
     <h2>Login do Usuário</h2>         
   </div>  
   <div class="form-label-group">
     <input type="email" id="emailLogin" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" [(ngModel)]="usuario"/>         
   </div>
   <div class="form-label-group">
     <input type="password" id="senhaLogin" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua senha" [(ngModel)]="senha"/> 
   </div>
   <div class="form-label-group"> 
     <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" (click)="loginUsuario()" >Entrar</button>         
     </div>          
  </form>
```

**Component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-usuario-page',
  templateUrl: './login-usuario-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-usuario-page.component.css'],  
})
export class LoginUsuarioPageComponent implements OnInit {  

  public usuario = "";  
  public senha = "";


  constructor() {
     }

  ngOnInit() {
     }

  loginUsuario() : void{     
    alert(this.usuario + " - " + this.senha);
     }
}
```

Comment: Verifique que esta importando o formsModule no modulo que vc delcara esse componente

Comment: @EduardoVargas Era um atributo na tag input que estava faltando, no meu caso era o atributo name. O formsModule já estava declarado sim, no componente principal da aplicação, e era lá mesmo que eu declarava meu componente.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui solucionar, o problema era um atributo da tag `input` do template, estava **faltando** o atributo `name`. Sendo assim eu fiz a seguinte alteração **somente** nas tag´s `input`:

```
`<input type="email" name="email" id="emailLogin" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" [(ngModel)]="usuario"/>

<input type="password" name="senha" id="senhaLogin" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua senha" [(ngModel)]="senha"/>
```

`